# ASP.NET MVC Date input format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, format, culture

I have a textbox with date type:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
```

of the model's field DateOfBirth

```
   [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; } // Дата рождения
```

But date format is static **mm/dd/yy** which is wrong for Russian (**dd/mm/yy**). Of course I can set date format manually, but the system is multi-lingual and has English language as well as Russian, Kyrgyz, Uzbek (they all use European formats). When a user change a language

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
```

He supposed to see appropriate date format. But somewhy it doesn't happen :(

**I have explored that the format depends on the language the browser uses. But chrome can't be displayed in Kyrgyz language...**

Comment: It looks like it is not possible to have a custom format for the  HTML5 "date" input (Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/967736 ) . You could create your own custom web component (like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32149869/967736 ), or you could use a good and old jQuery date picker plugin (or Angular, React, Vue, ...) for the job. If you are aiming for browsers compatibility and a consistent UX across different browsers I would suggest NOT using the input type date, since the rendering of such input will be the responsibility of the web browser.

Comment: @IPValverde Thank you for answering! I've actually use the jQuery's date picker, but couldn't make it multi-lingual. `<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        $.extend(
            { 'dateFormat': 'dd-mm-yy' },
            $.datepicker.regional["fr"]
        )
    );
</script>` It was still English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using the jquery.ui datepicker. By using it (or any other library that provides a similar functionality) you can easily maintain a consistent UX across multiple browsers, while with the standard HTML5 date inputs (`<input type="date" />`) you'll have browser-specific behaviour.

You can simply set the datepicker "regional" when loading your page. It seems that one of your goals is to be able to address multiple languages, I would recommend sticking with the "localization" idea rather than just setting the `dateFormat` attribute. If jquery ui does not provide a localization for the culture you are looking for, create one.

I've created a simple example where you can see the localization working in client-side. The idea would be very similar, but in your case it would be in the server-side: https://jsfiddle.net/ipvalverde/wxLxLe7p/9/

Regarding ASP.net MVC, I would suggest you to create a Razor View to setup all your datepicker elements on screen with your culture info. Something like this:

```
@{
    _Layout = null;
}

var currentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
string cultureCode = currentCulture.Name;

string datepickerLocalization = // Convert the thread culture name to datepicker culture name...

<script>
    $(function () {
      $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["@datepickerLocalization"]);
    })
</script>
```

Make sure you have loaded the javascripts with localization for the supported languages.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This should help but didn't. I've added the datepicker-fr.js file, but nothing heppened

Comment: You won't believe, I did exactly the same

Comment: @AzizjanHamidovichAyupov can you assure that the `$.datepicker.regional["fr"]` is defined? And also, are you sure you are executing the `$.datepicker.setDefaults` **before** setting each input with `$("my-selector").datepicker()`?